# Parameter name hint not working for typescript static methods

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am using
[image]

I've this `Car` class

```
export default class Car {
    static totalCars = 0;

    constructor(public name: string, public model: number) {
        Car.totalCars++
    }

    static getReport = (template: string, lastCar : Car): string => {
        return `${template} : ${Car.totalCars}, Last car created : ${lastCar.name}, ${lastCar.model}`;
    }
}
```

and when I try to use the class

```
import Car from "./Car";

const bmw: Car = new Car("BMW", 2018);
const audi: Car = new Car("Audi", 2017);

console.log(Car.getReport('Total cars created: ', audi));
```

I am not getting parameter hint for **static method** `getReport`. (It works for constructors and member methods)

**Proof**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try [2018.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/eap/), I couldn't reproduce the issue there. And don't forget to enable "Show name for all arguments" in `Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show parameter name hints > Configure`.